# How to set up my snowboard binding for the backcountry

Tags: gear, backcountry, snowboarding

I'm riding a pretty standard "binding setting" since ever. Just didn't bother me yet because I always was extremely fit. Lately I recognized that it's not *that easy* anymore since I got older ;P and I wanted to try to adjust my gear so that it suits me perfectly.

However, I wonder which settings I should use for the backcountry? Please provide the most regular case from which one can start to setup his individual configurations.

A few key-facts:

- Backcountry-snowboarding is riding in deep, unprepared snow (off-piste)
- I've Forum Factions soft bindings
- Installed on +21°/+9° and highbacks are default (lowest)
  [image: Highbacks]
- Centered on both mounting points

Comment: Where are you snowboarding right now? it's march 24th :D

Answer (score 5):

Like a lot it comes down to preference. Assuming from your current setting you do not ride fakie/switch a lot. (Then something like +12°/-12° would more appropriate, and the following paragraph would be less helpful.)

Something that is preferable in deep powdery snow is to have a long nose and a short tail (which is something you can observe also in the design of specific freeride snowboards) which allows for an more relaxed "surfing", because it does not force you to put so much weight on the rear foot. So I recommend trying to shift both bindings somewaht back to the tail if possible. 
Also I like having the highbacks alot looser than for tight carving on well made hard pists.

Other than that I really recommend just trying out different settings and see what you are comfortable with.